# Show Badge at Ribbon Button with DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, badge, adorner

I try to add number badge to a Ribbon Bar Button for unread mails at a WinForm Project with devexpress. I try this code and first time it's work successfully I show badges but after I clean the cache and build the project it is not work anymore. I debug this code at run time and do not anything and not show any error.

```
Badge b = new Badge();
b.TargetElement = btnInbox;
b.Properties.Text = unreadMailCount.ToString();
b.Visible = true;
adornerUIManager1.Elements.Add(b);
```

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: No, there is not any error, its work when debug but do not show badges.

Comment: when you clean the cache, the badge count can be zero

Comment: I know but something not stabil at devexpress, it worked code time and as AdornerUı Element properties, but now not work both of them  @SaurabhJain

Comment: Is the AdornerUIManager's Owner property set to your Ribbon control? Does it work if you set the Badge's Text property to a literal string value?